# Relationship between SpringBoot actuator system.cpu.count metric and system.cpu.usage metric

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

Just would like to get some clarifications on the relationship between system.cpu.count metric and system.cpu.usage metric from SpringBoot 2.3.1 actuator metric endpoints.

For example, in my case:

The value of /actuator/metrics/system.cpu.count is: 2

The value of /actuator/metrics/system.cpu.usage is: 0.024765603908878

Does this mean that my cpu utilization percentage is: 0.024765603908878 / 2 * 100 = 1.24% ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The metrics are provided in Spring Boot by Micrometer, specifically by Micrometer's [`ProcessorMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/c77dd34f839a4971f80b0bf3609502c4105c9f6f/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/system/ProcessorMetrics.java). Looking at its source, we can learn that `system.cpu.count` is backed by `java.lang.Runtime.availableProcessors()` and `system.cpu.usage` is backed by `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad()`. Looking at those methods tells us that:

- `system.cpu.count` is the number of CPUs that are available to the JVM.
- `system.cpu.usage` is a value between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive where a value of 0.0 means that all CPUs were idle during the recent period of time observed, while a value of 1.0 means that all CPUs were actively running 100% of the time during the recent period being observed.

Your value of 0.025 indicates that CPU utilization was 2.5% of its total capacity. As you have two CPUs, this could be one CPU running at 5% and the other at 0%, both CPUs running at 2.5%, or any other combination in between.

Comment: Hi Andy, just wondering if system.cpu.usage is still a good/accurate metric while the application is running inside a docker container and this container is in turn running inside kubenetes.

In my case, I limit my pod to 1 cpu and run some load, when I run: kubectl top pod cpu-demo --namespace=cpu-example

I got: 
CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
989m            427Mi

which is almost 100% cpu utilization.

However, the value of /actuator/metrics/system.cpu.usage is still very low:

0.0741890070728695

Any thoughts?

Comment: It'll depend on how container-aware your JVM is. I believe that's improved in recent versions of Java in terms of respecting cgroup limits and the like. I'm not sure how, if at all, it affects the JVM's view of CPU load.