# How to get cpu usage in java other than using OperatingSystemMXBean?

Tags: java, cpu, cpu-usage, cgroups, mxbean

```
double getCPUUsage() {
        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
        return osBean.getProcessCpuLoad();
}
```

Cpu usage from above method is not giving as accurate cpu usage as kubernetes metrics.

This is same as spring boot metric `system_cpu_usage` as it also uses the same OperatingSystemMXBean in its implementation.

Other methods to get cpu usage in java?

Comment: Which tool did you use to determine that kubernetes metrics is more accurate than the method, JMX uses?

Comment: I just plotted the k8s metrics vs this method in grafana

Comment: That’s obviously a valid method for finding out that two graphs are different. But how did you determine whether and which one is more accurate than the other?

Comment: K8s is giving higher value compare to mxbean, According to last comment in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551170/relationship-between-springboot-actuator-system-cpu-count-metric-and-system-cpu It'll depend on how container-aware your JVM is